# parallel runtime is not as I expected

Tags: c, parallel-processing, rsa, openmp

I am trying to implement a parallel version of RSA algorithm using openMP. The program takes public key and N as a user input, calculate to prime numbers and generate public key and private key pairs and also generated encrypted and decrypted message. I paralyzed the for loop for public key generation in the main function. Now, the problem is that my program unable to calculate elapsed time. So I am skeptical that my parallel implementation did not work well.

The code block

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int GCD(int , int);
long int Decryption__k(long int , int );
unsigned Decryption(unsigned , unsigned, unsigned);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned public_key, n, totient, private_key, encryption, my_msg, plainText;
    unsigned f_prime, s_prime, temp = 0;
    double start, end;
    int thread_count=strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
     printf("Enter value for public key: ");
    scanf("%d", &public_key);

    printf("Enter value for N: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\nEnter encrypted message: ");
    scanf("%u", &my_msg);

    if(my_msg >= n){
        printf("\nError enter message small than N\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    
     start = omp_get_wtime();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            if(i % 2 == 1 && i != 1 && i != n){
                f_prime = i;
                if(f_prime != temp){
                    temp = f_prime;
                    f_prime = s_prime;
                    s_prime = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    totient = (f_prime - 1) * (s_prime - 1);
   
    bool flag = false;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count)
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(public_key=0; public_key < totient; public_key++){
        
        if(flag)continue;
        if(GCD(public_key, totient) == 1){
            encryption = public_key;
            flag=true;
        }
    }

    private_key = Decryption__k(encryption, totient);

    printf("\nPublic Key: {%u, %d}\nPrivate Key: {%u, %d}\n Prime 1 : %d\nPrime 2: %d\n", encryption, n, private_key, n, f_prime, s_prime);


    plainText = Decryption(my_msg, private_key, n);

    printf("\nEncrypted message: %u\nDecrypted message: %u\n", my_msg, plainText);

   
   end=omp_get_wtime();
    printf("\nElapsed time =%e seconds\n", end - start);

    return 0;
}

    long int Decryption__k(long int e, int totient)
{
  int d = 1;

  while ((e * d) % totient != 1) {
    d++;
  }
  return d;
}

unsigned Decryption(unsigned message, unsigned key, unsigned n)
{
    unsigned r = 1;

    for (unsigned a = 1, p = message; a <= key; a <<= 1, p = p * p % n){
        if (key & a){
            r = r * p % n;
        }
    }

    return r;
}

int GCD(int a, int b)
{
    int temp;
    while (b != 0)
    {
        temp = a % b;

        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Output:

[image]

As per the output elapsed time is nan

I did not include GCD, Decryption__k, and Decryption function here because I did not implement paralization there.

Thank you

Comment: You subtract `start` from `end`. It should be `end - start`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if `%e` is the format specifier you want to use here. Since it [converts floating-point numbers to the decimal exponent notation.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) Maybe you meant to use `%lf`?

Comment: Even if I modify the code the error persist.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. And I can't reproduce it. Maybe you have edited something you haven't shown us?

Comment: Your `start` computation is in a parallel region. I wonder if that's the problem. Eitehr put it before the parallel region, or make it `omp single`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I have edited the code and reload the output. I did not get correct result as well as time. I believe I can not follow you. Can you please make a change in my code block?

Comment: @Encipher You have to provide the rest of the code, how you compile it and a sample input. The way it is now, if I exclude the functions that you haven't shared, I can get a valid output.

Comment: I shared the whole code that I have written. The problem is I can not understand which in portion I need to implement parallel coding using openMP.

Comment: Your code as above runs fine with me.

Comment: If there is no parallel implementation its run fine. But whenever I used #pragma directives  it produced the output that I shared. Certainly, the above o/p is not ok

Comment: My suggestion is to first check your serial code: 1)  `f_prime` and `s_prime` are uninitialized. 2) `if(i % 2 == 1 && i != 1 && i != n)` is not a proper condition to find a prime number  3)  `bool flag = false;  if(flag)continue;` is always false, you may wish to move `bool flag = false;` before the loop.  4) Note that to parallelize that loop you have to take care of data race as well, so a single line of  `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_count)` is not enough.

Comment: @Laci I initialize f_prime, s_prime here `unsigned f_prime, s_prime, temp = 0;` For point 2 what would be the proper condition of checking prime? 3) I have changed my code block. 4) #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_count) is not enough what should I add?

Comment: Can anyone please take a look in this code I have modify the code little bit and change the prime number implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71891372/parallel-execution-of-openmp-got-stuck-after-taking-some-input